# Black line appearing in my mesh

Tags: modeling

There’s a black line appearing in my mesh. I have recalculated normals, merged vertices, and this is still appearing. how do I fix this?

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: could be interior faces, duplicate geometry or normals. What does select non manifold show?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply.

It was the modifiers causing the issue, I added some more thickness to the solidify and bumped up the subsurface from 2 to 3, and the mesh looks clean.

Kind regards.